# Handle Try catch block in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I have to try-catch block for stripe payment to handle error responses, Now I am using laravel to code.

But after catching it gives me 500 internal server error, instead of storing an exception message, it catches the error with **500 Internal Server**?

Here is my code:

```
try {
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
        'email' => $email,
        'source' => $token,
    ]);

    $customer_id = $customer->id;
    $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create([
        'customer' => $customer_id,
        'items' => [['plan' => 'plan_id']], //plan-id is static as there is single plan
    ]);


    $chargeJson = $subscription->jsonSerialize(); 
}
catch(Stripe_CardError $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
} catch (Stripe_InvalidRequestError $e) {

    // Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
    $error = $e->getMessage();
} catch (Stripe_AuthenticationError $e) {

    // Authentication with Stripe's API failed
    $error = $e->getMessage();
} catch (Stripe_ApiConnectionError $e) {

    // Network communication with Stripe failed
    $error = $e->getMessage();
} catch (Stripe_Error $e) {

    // Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
    // yourself an email
    $error = $e->getMessage();
} catch (Exception $e) {

    // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}

$resp = array();
if(isset($chargeJson) && !empty($chargeJson['id'])) {

    $resp['status'] = 1;
    $resp['transactions_log'] = $chargeJson;
    $resp['current_period_end'] = $chargeJson['current_period_end'];
    $resp['transaction_id'] = $chargeJson['id']; // which is actually subcsription id
} else {

    $resp['status'] = 0;
    $resp['error'] = $error;
}
return $resp;
```

I am not sure how to handle it and store it. 
I am pretty much sure I have catched the exception but I can't store it and further use it.

Comment: Are you importing all those exception classes ? if your code is `namespaced` you need to catch \Exception and not Exception.

Comment: What is the 500 message you see? These exception types seem incorrect. I would expect `\Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException $e` and similar based on this doc:

based on https://stripe.com/docs/api/errors/handling?lang=php